# Stanford NLP: set RegexNERAnnotator to caseInsensitive

Tags: nlp, stanford-nlp

I am identifying qualifications in a large corpus. I am using NamedEntityTagAnnotation.

Problem:

My annotations are read in as case sensitive. I want them to be case insensitive.
Hence

Bachelor's Degree   DEGREE

does not need an additional entry of

Bachelor's degree   DEGREE

I know this is possible. RegexNERAnnotator has a field for ignoreCase. But I don't know how to access RegexNERAnnotator  through the API.

My current code  (which I cadged off the internet and works apart from the case issue) is as follows:

```
        String prevNeToken = "O";
    String currNeToken = "O";
    boolean newToken = true;
    for (CoreLabel token : sentence.get(TokensAnnotation.class))
    {
      currNeToken = token.get(NamedEntityTagAnnotation.class);

      String word = token.get(TextAnnotation.class);

      if (currNeToken.equals("O"))
      {

        if (!prevNeToken.equals("O") && (sbuilder.length() > 0))
        {
          handleEntity(prevNeToken, sbuilder, tokens);
          newToken = true;
        }
        continue;
      }

      if (newToken)
      {
        prevNeToken = currNeToken;
        newToken = false;
        sbuilder.append(word);
        continue;
      }

      if (currNeToken.equals(prevNeToken))
      {
        sbuilder.append(" " + word);
      }
      else
      {

        handleEntity(prevNeToken, sbuilder, tokens);
        newToken = true;
      }
      prevNeToken = currNeToken;
    }
```

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is in how you set up the pipeline.

```
    Properties props = new Properties();

    props.put("annotators", "tokenize, ssplit, pos, lemma, ner, parse, regexner, depparse,  natlog,  openie");


    //props.put("regexner.mapping", namedEntityPropertiesPath);

    pipeline = new StanfordCoreNLP(props);
    pipeline.addAnnotator(new TokensRegexNERAnnotator(namedEntityPropertiesPath, true));
```

Do *not* use props.put("regexner.mapping", namedEntityPropertiesPath);

Use pipeline.addAnnotator.

The first argument to the constructor is the path to your NER data file. The second is a boolean caseInsensitive.

Note, that this then uses Stanford's NER lists as well as your own. It also uses a more complex NER data file.

See http://nlp.stanford.edu/nlp/javadoc/javanlp/edu/stanford/nlp/pipeline/TokensRegexNERAnnotator.html